# How do I correct/set/syncronize time on Watchguard Firebox X500?

Tags: firewall, watchguard, firebox

Looking at the logs on my firewall in realtime it appears that the time is slow by about 13 minutes. I might not have noticed but I'm troubleshooting a lan to lan VPN connection.

It may be purely cosmetic or it might actually be an issue if the time is too far out of synch. Either way I'd like to correct the time on the firewall.

Can anyone tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your model I believe the system time gets set from the log host, so you'll need to install and configure a log host in order to set the time.

http://watchguard.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/watchguard.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1808&p_created=1226779208&p_sid=HapC7wHj&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_lva=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MjQyLDI0MiZwX3Byb2RzPTAmcF9jYXRzPSZwX3B2PSZwX2N2PSZwX3BhZ2U9MSZwX3NlYXJjaF90ZXh0PXRpbWU*&p_li=&p_topview=1

Comment: Josh's suggestion is for devices behind the firewall to have access to NTP, that was already in place on this firewall. Joeqwery's suggestion led me to http://watchguard.custhelp.com/cgi-bin/watchguard.cfg/php/enduser/std_adp.php?p_faqid=1721&p_sid=l7YH9wHj&p_lva=1808&p_accessibility=0&p_redirect=&p_sp=cF9zcmNoPTEmcF9zb3J0X2J5PSZwX2dyaWRzb3J0PSZwX3Jvd19jbnQ9MjQyLDI0MiZwX3Byb2RzPTAmcF9jYXRzPSZwX3B2PSZwX2N2PSZwX3BhZ2U9MSZwX3NlYXJjaF90ZXh0PXRpbWU#Troubleshooting%20the%20log%20host%20[WFS] and setting up a working log fixed the time on the firewall.

Answer (score 0):

According to Watchguard it should be as simple as launching Policy Manager and following the steps on this page: http://www.watchguard.com/help/WSM/83/basicfireboxadmin9.html

Make sure you configure it to use a local time server, or pool.ntp.org